# How do i combine a list and a form in the same page using django?

Tags: django, templates

Am building a Q&A page, sort of stackoverflow kinda page! Am having a bit of a problem trying to render the form. Am pasing 3 objects to the template that renders the page i.e. Question object, Answers related to the question and Answer form object.

In the first part of the page i want to display the Question, then the answers list follows, then at the bottom  i display my form to enter the new answer.

On my template when i use the {{ extends "base_site.html" }} tag then only the form get rendered, 
When i remove that tag then only the Question section  get displayed minus the form!!

How can i go round this problem?

Comment: Show some template code and the possibly the view as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky to answer without seeing some code, but I suspect it's something to do with the way you are using {{ extends }} and inheriting/over-riding {{ block }} sections.

I would check the names of all your {{ block }} sections, and that you are over-riding the blocks that you think you are. It may be that you have blocks in the inheriting page that aren't defined in the base page?